# Installing python-dev in virtualenv

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv

I am trying to install mysqlclient for python in my virtualenv. It fails with the following:

```
 #include "Python.h"

                ^

compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

After some research, i found out that i require python-dev installation. I have it installed in my main directories (i.e /usr/bin ... ) but its not installed virtualenv but each time i type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

I get the following response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 453 not upgraded.
```

Showing its availability, outside the virtualenv mysqlclient installs properly. The issue is how to rectify python-dev installation into the virtualenv

Comment: @downshift doesn't work .. python-dev executable not found.

Comment: @downshift python-dev is not an executable but a set of `*.h` header.

Comment: @Subomi.js What version of Python? For Python 3 you need `python3-dev`.

Comment: Yea, @phd .. but because of the shared libraries, would it be proper to just try and copy the header files and it will still work?

Comment: No. Python 2 and Python 3 are very much incompatible, especially at the C level.

Comment: @phd python3-dev how will it enter my virtualenv .. am doing python3.4

Comment: `python3-dev` is a set of headers. It will be used by a compiler during `pip install`. The compiler should find the headers itself.

Comment: @phd so what i need to is to download the headers and put them where pip can find them in the virtual env?

Comment: Oops .. I appears, I was using python-dev for python 2.7. As you pointed that i needed, python3-dev .. I went back and activated the virtualenv and did `apt-get install python3-dev` and `pip install mysqlclient` .. everything seems to be working fine now. I don't completely understand why i works tho' .. But it does now, thanks.

Comment: @Subomi How will `apt-get install python3-dev` add header files to the virtual environment? I am facing a similar issue where I require `python3-dev` for a virtual environment. Please let me know if you were able to solve this and how. Thanks.

Comment: @saharudra hi, once you activate your virtualenv. It changes your PATH variables and so when you do apt-get intsall python3-dev you're installing it into the proper location where the python3 compiler can locate the headers.

Comment: I get the following error after activating the virtualenv and running `apt-get install python3-dev` : ```E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```. With sudo, this will add the headers at the system level and not for the virtualenv.

Answer (score 4):

I am currently having issue in Ubuntu 20 where the default python is python 3.8. This causes issue when I try to install Pillow in a virtualenv created by `pipenv` that need to use python 3.9.

The simplest solution I found so far is to install python-dev for 3.9

```
sudo apt install python3.9-dev
```

Previously I install `python3-dev` which always default to 3.8

Answer (score 2):

pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is simply magic as it allows you to install different versions of Python, dev included (list available versions with `pyenv install --list`).  Sometimes I run into problems of the "Python library not found" sort and Ubuntu suggests building with "--enable-shared".  This can be done with pyenv as follows:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS=--enable-shared pyenv install 3.9-dev
```

It is also worth checking out pyenv-virtualenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best way but my solution was installing [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). You can also probably try the larger Anaconda distribution. I believe these distributions have built-in python-dev.

Answer (score 0):

This is because virtualenv not link include and lib directory to virtualenv's directory. I solve this by using anaconda virtual env.
wish helps.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04, I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-server) to successfully set up a Python virtual environment with python3-dev.

Comment: `apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev` (from the linked article) solved the issue but it downgraded GCC version, bringing another problem.

Answer (score -4):

I believe python-dev will already be installed. you may not be including the header files path while compiling.

u can search for Python.h by:

`find <venv folder> | grep Python.h`

If it is not able to find the file in your virtual environment, a simple command like below should install it:

`pip install python-dev (or python2/3.x-dev)`

Once u have the path, you need to compile your file by adding that path, for example if you are using conda:

`gcc <<your prev command args>> -I/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/<<vinv_name>>/include/python3.7m/`

If you are using a make utility you can also set the path in C_INCLUDE_PATH (or CPP_INCLUDE_PATH if using c++) by using export as:

`export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/<<vinv_name>>/include/python3.7m/`